# Blacklist the LMGTFY tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

Recently, [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29157) started to resurrect the [lmgtfy](/questions/tagged/lmgtfy) tag. It's an obvious metatag that until I saw it I didn't even know existed.

I have removed these tags, so it's empty again. Can it be consigned to the flames now?

Comment: People snap in many different ways

Comment: Did someone let this user know that this behavior is unacceptable? Posting the *link* is bad enough. Assigning the *tag*? That's almost suspension-worthy.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: I would have, but sending messages directly to a person on SO isn't easy. He didn't see any comments I could respond to.

Comment: I'd have flagged for a moderator to do it. They have seekrit tools.

Comment: @TheEstablishment That's not something we disclose, but we're aware of it (we were before this came up, actually) and will take the appropriate steps (if any, if needed).

Comment: @cas Wasn't asking for a disclosure. I was simply asking if someone had alerted a moderator. Glad you guys are on top of it.

Comment: @TheEstablishment [Did someone let this **user**...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131446/blacklist-the-lmgtfy-tag#comment362524_131446) - That doesn't sound like a moderator?

Comment: @NicolBolas I *think* you can @-reply on a question to a user who edited the question, even if they never left an answer on that question, and it will show up in their global inbox.

Comment: I'm a year late to the party, but [here](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2003-02-16/)'s what @random my be referring to...