# Newsletters should not contain duplicate posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, newsletter

I noticed that this week's MSO newsletter contains the same question twice. The script to generate these (assuming it is a script?) shouldn't do this.

[image]

Comment: Obviously it is a human doing this. Only humans make such mistakes as duplicating questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We failed to consider that the three newsletter sections, "Top new questions this week", "Greatest hits from previous weeks", and questions with no answers ("Can you answer these?"), aren't mutually exclusive.

For example, the [question in question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131446/blacklist-the-lmgtfy-tag) currently is "hot" *and* has no answers.

This is fixed now.